# Why explicitly run CLI commands outside EF applications to handle migration?

Tags: entity-framework, migration

[The documentation for Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) says to use migration CLI commands to create a database that doesn't exist yet for our EF model, and sync a database when our EF model changes.

Why do we need to explicitly run CLI commands outside our application in order to handle migration?
Can our applications that use EF implicitly handle migration: create a database if it doesn't exist for our EF model and sync a database when our EF model changes?

I had a little experience with Hibernate before, and  I didn't hear about migration then. I might be wrong but left with the impression that applications using Hibernate could handle migration implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either one you want.  If you have a formal DevOps deployment process you would normally deploy your database schema then, and the CLI commands are how you do that with Migrations.  You can run the migration in the deployment pipeline, or use the CLI to generate the upgrade scripts and run the scripts in the deployment pipeline.

See

> Some apps may want to apply migrations at runtime during startup or
>   first run. Do this using the Migrate() method. . . .
>
> Warning
>
> This approach isn't for everyone. While it's great for apps with a
>   local database, most applications will require more robust deployment
>   strategy like generating SQL scripts.

[Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime)

So while you would normally apply migrations at runtime on your private developer database, for deployment to shared environments it't often not the best choice.